# Toast in SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, toast

I want to create a message with Toast inside a SurfaceView class. With this code I have the follow Exception ...

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
```

11-05 02:06:08.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(265): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

How can I do a toast in SurfaceView ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to show Toast with the UI thread.  Whenever you initialize the SurfaceView, do something like this:

```
Handler handler;
private void initMe()
{
    handler = new Handler();
}
```

Then, wherever you want to make the toast, do this:

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

You need to make sure "initMe" is called from the UI thread.  You're *probably* initing the SurfaceView from onCreate, which is called by the UI thread, so you'd be good (I'm assuming this is a custom SufaceView extension class?)

Comment: It shows a warning ... " The method getContext() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){} "

Comment: Right.  Either "MyActivity.this.getContext()" or possibly just "getContext()" without the 'this'.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a Toast inside a SurfaceView class directly without using any Handlers.

If you are using the keyword "this" inside a inner class, but intend to get the object of the activity(outer/encapsulating) class, you need to use it's class-name like "MainActivity.this" instead. This is a concept some mediocre Java developers might not be knowing.

Or, you can create a static object of Context and assign to it the context of the activity, and then simply use it anywhere you need the context of it.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use in Your SurfaceView:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```